# How to append text in selected option only in select box

Tags: html, jquery, angular

Can anybody tell how to append text "Sort by" for selected value in dropdown, Eg If user select TlX in dropdown need to show selected value Sortby: TLX for seelcted value. But Option should not change . I need to append Sortby Text: for all values. If user selected value

```
 <select name="product" id="product" width="300" style="width: 300px">
      <option id="TLX">TLX</option>
      <option id="FLX">FLX</option>
      <option id="MLX">MLX</option>
    </select>
```

is it possible to append Sortby: text in selected value in dropdown?

I want to show selected value like this Sort by: TLX
inside dropdown

Thanks

Comment: This is written really confusing `need to show sort by but not sort by...`?!? Where is that `sort by` or how would it change in the first place? All I see is a select list in HTML.

Comment: What does this question have to do with either `jquery` or `angular`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to display the selected value with prefix sort By in a seperate line like this?

```js
const dropdown = document.getElementById('product');
const selectedOption = document.getElementById('selectedOption');

dropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {
  const selectedValue = dropdown.value;
  selectedOption.textContent = `Sort by: ${selectedValue}`;
});
```

```html
<select name="product" id="product" width="300" style="width: 300px">
  <option value="TLX">TLX</option>
  <option value="FLX">FLX</option>
  <option value="MLX">MLX</option>
</select>

<div id="selectedOption"></div>
```

Comment: I want to show it dropdown itself

Comment: On the 'change' event, 'Sort by:' in values of all options can be replaced with the empty text. And, the selected value can be  prepended with 'Sort by: '.